# How to evaluate $\int ({x\sin^2{x}-x^2\sin x\cos x})dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

If I use $u=\sin^2{x}$, then I need to deal with the $x$. But then I need to integrate $\arcsin$, which I don't think is right. Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: Do you know integration by parts?

Comment: **Hint:** What's $\cos(2x)$? What's $\sin(2x)$? How do you calculate, say, $\int t\sin t\,dt$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\int  ({x\sin^2{x}-x^2\sin x\cos x})dx=$$
$$\int x\sin x(\sin x-x\cos x)dx$$
Substitute $\sin x-x\cos x=t$, $dt=x\sin xdx$
$$=\int tdt$$
$$=\frac{t^2}{2}+C$$
You can now put $t$ back.